# Funny performance results comparing float and double in C# .net 4.0

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I made a small test program that multiplies and adds 10 million numbers. With float it always takes 51ms. With double it takes between 210 and 3310ms between compilations (3310ms happens only every 10 compilations or so). What's going on here?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            testCalc(1f,2f,3f);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print((DateTime.Now-now).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
            now = DateTime.Now;
            testCalcDouble(1, 2, 3);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print((DateTime.Now - now).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());

        }

        private void testCalc(float a, float b, float c)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                a++;
                c--;
                float d = (a + b) * c;
            }
        }

        private void testCalcDouble(double a, double b, double c)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            {
                a++;
                c--;
                double d = (a + b) * c;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you running it in Release or Debug mode? From the command line or from the debugger?

Comment: I'm running in Debug mode in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Erwin: Please don't measure performance for debug builds. Debug builds are not optimized, so the numbers are not worth much.

Comment: @Erwin: Also, `DateTime` is not really useful for measuring performance. Use `Stopwatch` instead.

Comment: To make the test meaningful, I think you need to do something with the result d, such as storing it in an array. Here you are storing the result of the calculation in a temporary variable and the compiler probably recognizes it can just throw it away.

Comment: On my Core i5 machine with VS2010, both loops run in 40ms +/- 10% no matter how many times I run the loops or recompile. Are you running in a VM by any chance?

Comment: Are you testing the same compile several times with the same result if not, maybe some other process on your machine caused the delay.

Comment: @Gabe: Thanks for trying it out on your machine. I have an older Core 2 quad. I'm not running on a VM and I don't have CPU intensive background processes running. I compiled it in Release mode. Now the float test is always 38ms+/-1 and the double varies from 76ms to 2175ms (mostly 127ms).

Comment: @Asaf: yes, once it's compiled the results stay the same no matter how many times I push the button.

Comment: On my Core 2 Duo (in Release mode) it runs in 75ms for floats and 150ms for doubles under the debugger, but about 51ms for both floats and doubles *not* under the debugger.

Comment: @Gabe: If I run the exe directly I also get the same results for float and double! Finally the mystery is solved :)

Comment: Erwin: You can just use Ctrl+F5 to run not under the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closed: it only happens while running in the debugger